2000's movie that wife's lover poisons the husband to death
I'm looking for a 2000's movie that wife and her lover makes a plan to kill the husband to be together because the husband didn't want to get divorced. 
There was an argument between wife and the husband at the opening scene. After that she did make-up, got dressed and left the house. He was all alone. After a while a salesman with a bag rang the bell. The husband didn't want to buy anything but the salesman insisted for a while. Eventually he got in the house. 
He was selling tropical fruits in the glass jars. They started to conversation but they barely talked about fruits. The dialogue was about relationships, life, family, etc.. They drank a bottle of drink also. Wine or whiskey, i couldn't remember that. It was the main part of the movie. Finally the salesman gave the fruits to the husband for free. 
He ate it and got poisoned in a short time. The salesman revelaled his identity and told him that this was a plan to kill him. 
Year: Early 2000's
Orgin country: I don't remember
Language: It was dubbed in my language
Duration: Between 70 -120
Budget: Low

It was dubbed in your language, but do you have any idea what the original language was?  What country it came from?

@Steve-O I can say it could be English, French, German or some other North-Western European languages. The orgin country is probably Usa, Canada or one of the West or Northern European countries. It wasn't Asian or South American made movie.

@madmada Indeed. I wish there was a way around that rule, because they're clearly identical.
